# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I'm building a real time chat application with firebase and angular. Actually I'm trying to get the message from the db but i have this error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays.

service

```
getMessage(url: string) {
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
```

logic

```
messages: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
this.chatService
      .getMessage('https://DB_URL/message.json')
      .subscribe((resMessage) => {
        this.messages = resMessage;
        console.log(this.messages);
      });
}
```

template

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages">
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
```

I don't know to resolve it, surely i'm missing something

I have not posted the whole code because the post would be too long

Comment: As the error states, your object needs to be an array. Look at your console.log it's most likely a json object.

Comment: @penleychan yes, console.log is a json object, how can i fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, initialize the messages variable as an array:

`messages = [];`

Then try pushing the message key from the object that you're getting from the server.

`this.messages.push(resMessage.yourMessageKey);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I initialize the messages variable as an array, but i don't understand the 2nd hint. I can't get the key from the object... When I do this.messages.push(resMessage.) after the subscribe, i can't get the key and  I get this error: 

`Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

Comment: Initialize your array like this by giving it a type of any

`messages: any[] = [];`